# tax_query not working on main query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pre-get-posts, tax-query

I'm using the following code to do a tax_query and it doesn't seem to work anymore..

At some point it was working and for the life of me it wont, anymore.

```
<?php

global $pf_override;

class PF_override {

    public $site_terms = array();

    function __construct() {

        // add filters
        add_filter( 'init', array( &$this, 'populates_site_terms' ) );
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'filter_query' ) );
    }

    function populates_site_terms() {

        // my actual function does some processing and
        // checks caches and combines IDs from multiple
        // different sources here and then sets site_terms 

        $this->site_terms = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    }

    function filter_query( $query ) {

        // not the main query?
        if ( !$query->is_main_query() ) {
            return $query;
        }

        // have terms to filter by?
        if ( !empty( $this->site_terms ) ) {

            // construct tax_query
            $tax_query = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'site_category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $this->site_terms,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
                );

            // this needs to be an array of arrays
            $taxquery = array(
                $tax_query
            );

            // set this..
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
        }

        // return new query object
        return $query;
    }
}

// not the admin? init class
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    $pf_override = new PF_override();
}

?>
```

Taxonomy is added like so:

```
function PF_register_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Site Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Site Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Site Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Site Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Site Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Site Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Site Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Site Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Site Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Site Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Site Category' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'sitecat' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'site_category', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'PF_register_post_types', 1 );
```

In my footer.php I add this code:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request
```

I get this as a result when going to mydomain.com/testing:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'testing' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

The $pf_override variable shows $pf_override->site_terms to be set as an array of

```
array( [0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems after digging in to the code, tax_query is being blocked on single post/page pages which is why I'm running in to this issue.

**If you see the ability to run tax_query in all circumstances as beneficial, please voice your opinion on trac.**

See ticket here:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24819

I managed to get around this by duplicating the core code for singular posts and appending to the join and where clauses. The new code is as follows:

```
<?php

global $pf_override;

class PF_override {

    public $site_terms = array();

    public $sql_join    = '';
    public $sql_where   = '';

    function __construct() {

        // add filters
        add_filter( 'init', array( &$this, 'populates_site_terms' ) );
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'filter_query' ) );
        add_filter( 'posts_join', array( &$this, 'filter_join' ) );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', array( &$this, 'filter_where' ) );
    }

    function populates_site_terms() {

        // my actual function does some processing and 
        // checks caches and combines IDs from multiple 
        // different sources here and then sets site_terms 

        $this->site_terms = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    }

    function filter_query( $query ) {

        // not the main query?
        if ( !$query->is_main_query() ) {
            return $query;
        }

        // have terms to filter by?
        if ( !empty( $this->site_terms ) ) {

            // construct tax_query
            $tax_query = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'site_category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $this->site_terms,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
                );

            // this needs to be an array of arrays
            $taxquery = array(
                $tax_query
            );

            // set this..
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );

            if ( $query->is_singular ) {

                global $wpdb;

                $q = &$query->query_vars;

                $q['suppress_filters'] = false;

                $query->parse_tax_query( $q );

                $clauses = $query->tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

                $this->sql_join     .= $clauses['join'];
                $this->sql_where    .= $clauses['where'];
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }

    function filter_join( $join ) {

        if ( !empty( $this->sql_join ) ) {
            $join .= $this->sql_join;
        }

        return $join;
    }

    function filter_where( $where ) {

        if ( !empty( $this->sql_where ) ) {
            $where .= $this->sql_where;
        }

        return $where;
    }
}

// not the admin? init class
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    $pf_override = new PF_override();
}

?>
```

Comment: Why would you need a tax query on a single post?

Comment: My particular WordPress instance is a web application that powers around 18,000 website and the individual posts and pages belong to this "site_category" that individual sites "subscribe" to. If the current site is subscribed to category 1 but not category 2, I don't want to show pages that belong to category 2 for that particular site and they need to return 404. It's basically a different low-overhead version of doing a WordPress MultiSite.

Comment: @DustinDempsey, it works, but How much code for a such simple task! There is a simpler solution...

Comment: This solution combines everything in to one query, keeping performance in mind, and uses some nice OOP.
Simpler isn't always better.

Comment: Appreciate this is a super old post, but your code has come in useful for me in 2021 - thanks. It's worth bearing in mind for anyone else that this code assumes you're not running any queries _after_ the main one - otherwise the clauses will be added to those too. To prevent, simply empty the class properties after appending them to their filter - i.e `$join .= $this->sql_join;` `$this->sql_join = '';`

Answer (score 1):

I want give a simple solution.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_query');

function filter_query( $query ) {
  // **PLEASE NOTE**
  // $this->site_terms refers specifically to logic in the question
  if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_singular && ! empty( $this->site_terms ) ) {
    $site = get_queried_object();
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($site->ID, 'site_category', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    if ( empty($terms) || empty( array_intersect($terms, $this->site_terms) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'page_id', -1 ); // 404
    }
  }
}
```

As extra benefit, changing `$query->set( 'page_id', -1 );` with the id of a page specifically created is possible redirect visitors to a page you want, instead of force a 404 error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you are missing an `add_action` to add this to `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: @helgatheviking I wrote in my answer: "*filter_query method in the question can contain...*" and `filter_query` method in question is called on `pre_get_posts`

Comment: I have edited the answer as @helgatheviking advised, so now my solution can used independently from answer logic.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see it in the OP's question, but I think you're answer is more useful to future readers now. +1 from me, pre_get_posts for the win!

Comment: This simpler solution adds multiple more database queries. 
It will query each taxonomy referenced (only 1 in this case) and then run a SELECT with multiple JOINs and a WHERE clause.

Additionally, there is the possibility of yet another SQL query. 

Though it may be simpler for all general purposes, my particular code uses an existing OOP class used within my specific code and I cannot afford to run the overhead of these additional queries on a high traffic platform when I can simply modify the original main query.

Comment: Additionally, Using get_queried_object() will run even more queries on top of that.
It's sad to say that in this case I think the simpler solution is not the best solution. (It still however is a solution.)

Comment: Main query is not very different from one runned by wp_get_object_terms. In a not high traffic site you can smoothly pay a handful of millisecond and get simpler and more flexible solution: on fail you obtain the standard 404, with my solution you can choose where to send people. All two solutions get the outcome, so I think everyone can choose wich prefer.

Comment: You run the queries from wp_get_object_terms and then you also run a duplicate query for the main query with get_queried_object just to determine if you should then do the main query.
Why not combine all that in to one query, the main query, in a fashion that doesn't slow performance?
Milliseconds add up and enough changes to WordPress like this on a single page load in an environment that can't take it and your site will slow to a crawl.
This solution just isn't as efficient and is poor practice.

Comment: You are welocome Dustin. Just a couple of notes: If you want, using my solution, you can never run the main query, change  `$query->set( 'page_id', -1 )`; with `wp_redirect` and `exit`. Then, `get_queried_object()`, for singular query, do not duplicate the main query, but run a simple and fast query. So with my solution (modded with wp_redirect) are fired 2 queries: 1 (complex) from wp_get_object_terms 1 (simple) from get_queried_object. Your solution perform 1 (complex) query, the main, so difference is one (simple) query: I think for site with not high traffic it is not a huge problem.