# WP_Query ignoring tax_query when is_singular

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, actions, pre-get-posts

I’m trying to set up some post permissions using taxonomies and I'm applying my rules in a `pre_get_posts` action.

It’s working fine when multiple posts are found, but in `class-wp-query.php` near [line 2060](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2060), it’s specifically not applying the `tax_query` rules when `is_singular` is `true`.

Is there a way around this without modifying core?

Comment: See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/107469/11761), it has two solutions. Also, there was a ticket on the WordPress Trac which was set to _wontfix_.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: What `tax_query` do you want to use exactly? Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `posts_clauses` filter and add processing for tax_query in there (you don't even need to write your own SQL):

```
function filter_single_with_tax_queries( $clauses, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $query->is_singular ) {  
        $query->parse_tax_query( $query->query_vars );
        $tax_clauses = $query->tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
        $clauses['join'] .= $tax_clauses['join'];
        $clauses['where'] .= $tax_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $parts;
}
add_action( 'posts_clauses', 'filter_single_with_tax_queries', 10, 2 );
```